# What am I supposed to use `O_PATH` for, and how?

Tags: file-descriptors, system-calls

I use a Linux 4.x-based distribution, and I've recently noticed the kernel's `open()` system call supports an `O_PATH` open flag.

While the `man` page for it does have a list of system calls it could theoretically be used with, I don't quite understand what the idea is. Do I `open(O_PATH)` only directories, rather than files? And if I do, why do I want to use a file descriptor instead of the directory's path? Also, most of the system calls listed there don't seem to be particular to directories; so, do I also open regular files with `O_PATH` to somehow get their directory as a file descriptor? Or to get a file descriptor for them but with limited functionality?

Can someone give a cogent explanation of what `O_PATH` is about and how, and what for, we're supposed to use it?

Notes:

- No need to describe the history of how this evolved (the relevant man pages mention changes in Linux 2.6.x, 3.5 and 3.6) unless necessary - I just care about how things are now.
- Please don't tell me to just use libc or other higher-level facilities, I know that.

Comment: related: [Semantics of Linux O_PATH file descriptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416889/semantics-of-linux-o-path-file-descriptors)

Comment: @sebasth: It is indeed related, but: 1. It's a bit old by now and things may have changed. 2. Frankly, I don't quite get the gist of the answer.

Comment: You could post comment in that question asking if anything has changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The description in the [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) man page gives some clues to start with:

```
   O_PATH (since Linux 2.6.39)
          Obtain a file descriptor that can be used for two purposes:
          to  indicate  a location in the filesystem tree and to per‐
          form operations that act  purely  at  the  file  descriptor
          level.  The file itself is not opened, and other file oper‐
          ations  (e.g.,  read(2),  write(2),  fchmod(2),  fchown(2),
          fgetxattr(2), ioctl(2), mmap(2)) fail with the error EBADF.
```

Sometimes, we don't want to open a file or a directory. Instead, we just want a reference to that filesystem object in order to perform certain operations (e.g., to `fchdir()` to a directory referred to by a file descriptor that we opened using `O_PATH`). So, a trivial point: if this is our purpose, then opening with `O_PATH` should be a little cheaper, since the file itself is not actually opened.

And a less trivial point: before the existence of `O_PATH`, the way of obtaining such a reference to a filesystem object was to open the object with `O_RDONLY`. But the use of `O_RDONLY` requires that we have read permission on the object. However, there are various use cases where we don't need to actually read the object: for example, executing a binary or accessing a directory (`fchdir()`) or reaching through a directory to touch an object inside the directory.

**Usage with "*at()" system calls**

The common, but not the only, use of `O_PATH` is to open a directory, in order to have a reference to that directory for use with the "*at" system calls, such as `openat()`, `fstatat()`, `fchownat()`, and so on. This family of system calls, which we can roughly think of as the modern successors to the older system calls with similar names (`open()`, `fstat()`, `fchown()`, and so on), serve a couple of purposes, the first of which you touch on when you ask "why do I want to use a file descriptor instead of the directory's path?". If we look further down in the `open(2)` man page, we find this text (under a subheading with the rationale for the "*at" system calls):

```
   First,  openat()  allows  an  application to avoid race conditions
   that could occur when using open() to open  files  in  directories
   other  than  the current working directory.  These race conditions
   result from the fact that some component of the  directory  prefix
   given  to  open()  could  be  changed in parallel with the call to
   open().  Suppose, for example, that we wish  to  create  the  file
   path/to/xxx.dep  if  the  file path/to/xxx exists.  The problem is
   that between the existence check and the file creation step,  path
   or  to  (which might be symbolic links) could be modified to point
   to a different location.  Such races can be avoided by  opening  a
   file descriptor for the target directory, and then specifying that
   file descriptor as the dirfd argument of (say) fstatat(2) and ope‐
   nat().
```

To make this more concrete... Suppose we have a program that wants to perform multiple operations in a directory other than its current working directory, meaning that we must specify some directory prefix as part of the filenames we use. Suppose, for example, that the pathname is `/dir1/dir2/file` and we want to perform two operations:

1. Perform some check on `/dir1/dir2/file` (e.g., who owns the file, or what time was it last modified).
2. If we are satisfied with the result of that check, perhaps we then want to do some other filesystem operation in the same directory, for example, creating a file called `/dir1/dir2/file.new`.

Now, first suppose we did everything using traditional pathname-based system calls:

```
struct stat stabuf;
stat("/dir1/dir2/file", &statbuf);
if ( /* Info returned in statbuf is to our liking */ ) {
    fd = open("/dir1/dir2/file.new", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0600);
    /* And then populate file referred to by fd */
}
```

Now, furthermore suppose that in the directory prefix `/dir1/dir2` one of the components (say `dir2`) was actually a symbolic link (that refers to a directory), and that **between the call to `stat()` and the call to `open()`** a malicious person was able to change the target of the symbolic link `dir2` to point to a different directory. This is a classic time-of-check-time-of-use race condition. Our program checked a file in one directory but was then tricked into creating a file in a different directory -- perhaps a security-sensitive directory. The key point here is that the pathname `/dir/dir2` looked the same, but what it refers changed completely.

We can avoid these sorts of problems using the "*at" calls. First of all, we obtain a handle referring to the directory where we will do our work:

```
dirfd = open("/dir/dir2", O_PATH);
```

The critical point here is that `dirfd` is a **stable** reference to the directory that was referred to by the path `/dir1/dir2` at the time of the `open()` call. If the target of the symbolic link `dir2` is subsequently changed, this will not affect what `dirfd` refers to. Now, we can do our check + operation using the "*at" calls that are equivalent to the `stat()` and `open()` calls above:

```
fstatat(dirfd, ""file", &statbuf)
struct stat stabuf;
fstatat(dirfd, "file", &statbuf);
if ( /* Info returned in statbuf is to our liking */ ) {
    fd = openat(dirfd, "file.new", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0600);
    /* And then populate file referred to by fd */
}
```

During these steps any manipulation of symbolic links in the pathname `/dir/dir2` will have no impact: the check (`fstatat()`) and the operation (`openat()`) are guaranteed to take place in the same directory.

There is another purpose to using the "*at()" calls, which relates to the idea of "per-thread current working directories" in multithreaded programs (and again we could open the directories using `O_PATH`), but I think this use is probably less relevant to your question, and I leave you to read the `open(2)` man page if you'd like to know more.

**Usage with file descriptors for regular files**

One usage of `O_PATH` with regular files is to open a binary for which we have execute permission (but not necessarily read permission, so that we could not open the file with `O_RDONLY`). That file descriptor can then be passed to [`fexecve(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fexecve.3.html) to execute the program. All that `fexecve(fd, argv, envp)` is doing with its `fd` argument is essentially:

```
snprintf(buf, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);
execve(buf, argv, envp);
```

(Although, starting with glibc 2.27, the implementation will instead make use of the [`execveat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execveat.2.html) system call, on kernels that provide that system call.)

Comment: `The problem is that between the existence check and the file creation step,  path or to ... could be modified ` - can't parse this sentence. But I get the gist of it, I think. So it's serves as a sort of a locking mechanism on a directory. But why use the `open()` result rather than an actual lock?

Comment: @einpoklum the problem is that 'path' and 'to' don't have the formatting shown in the original man page. These are components of the hypothetical pathname "/path/to/xxx". And, it's not like a lock: it's a stable reference to a filesystem object; several programs might have such reference to the same object.

Comment: The directory(/symlink/file) could, in fact, be unlinked (`rm`/`unlink()`) while you hold a reference/FD to it. However, the FD is (indirectly) a pointer to the actual blocks on disk, which will continue to be treated as "in-use" until the FD is closed - even though the name referencing them no longer exists. Waiting for lock = not doing anything: better to avoid locks.